# Python / Numpy: Triangle mask from point mask

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, mayavi

I'm working with a triangulated mesh consisting of points 3 x n and triangles specified by the point indices 3 x m. I can easily plot that e.g. using mlab

`mesh = mlab.triangular_mesh(p[0,:],p[1,:],p[2,:],t.T`

I am also generating a mask masking points which are out of bounds or `nan`, so I have a mask the size of n. Now I want to mask the triangles which have a masked point. My solutions so far:

**1: Use the mask to turn all masked points into `nan`, e.g.**

```
p[mask] = nan
```

`mlab` then still shows `nan` (I would need to include a threshold filter...) and I actually don't want to mess with my data

**2: Generating a triangle mask, which I started like this**

```
def triangleMask(triangles, pointmask):
    maskedTris = np.zeros((triangles.shape[1]), dtype=np.bool)
    maskedIdx = np.nonzero(pointmask)[0]
    for i,t in enumerate(triangles.T):
         if (i%5000) == 0:
             print('working it.:', i)
         for p in t:
             if p in maskedIdx:
                 maskedTris[i] = True
                 break

    return maskedTris
```

This works, but is not fast. And in my case, n = 250.000 and m = 500.000, so "not fast" is quite a problem.

I know there's a mask keyword in `mlab`, but I cant get it to work. Masking only the points in the triangular_mesh call yields and error since t then refers to indices which are larger than the size of p.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you have a `points` array of shape `(3, n)`, a `triangles` array of shape `(3, m)` and a `point_mask` boolean array of shape `(n,)`, and would like to create a `triangle_mask` of shape `(m,)` holding `True` at position `j` if any of the indices in `triangles[:, j]` corresponds to a `True` in `point_mask`. You can do that with a little bit of fancy indexing:

```
triangle_mask = np.any(point_mask[triangles], axis=0)
```

To understand what's going on, `point_mask[triangles]` creates a boolean array of shape `(3, m)`, with the value at position `(i, j)` being `point_mask[triangles[i, j]]`.

Comment: Guess thats quite similiar to what I was doing in my loop solution.Only that its a million times faster. Works great, thank you!